# Spring storing data in session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

Maybe it is obvious, but I am not 100% sure that I'm correct and I need confirmation.

Let's assume I want to store some data in session(using Spring Framework).
I understand that there are two different approaches and I want to know that I know the difference between them.

1. Creating a field in class annotated by @Component

I understand that class annotated by @Component is by default singleton. It means that it is created once per container. So it is shared between users/sessions, right?

2. Creating a field in class annotated @Component and scope set to session

Data is "remembered" only per one session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that class annotated by @Component is by default singleton. It means that it is created once per container. So it is shared between users/sessions, right?

Yes, singleton in scope of application.

> Creating a field in class annotated @Component and scope set to session - Data is "remembered" only per one session.

Depends on what you mean by that. But in general `@SessionScope` beans are created for every user session, and are singletos  in scope of that session, not application like in default scope. They are discarded once session is invalidated.

In order to keep something during session, use `@SessionScope`

> I understand that there are two different approaches and I want to know that I know the difference between them.

I belive that scopes should be self explainatory to you by now:)